# I'm having issues with this event calendar on python using nest dictionaries based on user input

Tags: python

```
event_dict={}
print'''
Welcome to Event Calendar:
    add: add an event
    list: list events for a date
    info: see information on an event
    quit: quit the program
'''
while True:
    action = raw_input('Enter a command (add, list, info, or quit): ')
    if action == 'add':
        event_date = raw_input('Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
        event_name = raw_input('Enter event name: ')
        event_location = raw_input('Location: ')
        event_description = raw_input('Description: ')
    if event_date and event_name in event_dict[event_date][event_name]: 
         print 'This event already exists'
    else:
        print 'Event Added.'
    if action == 'quit':
        print 'Exiting...'
        break
    if action == 'list':
        event_date = raw_input('Date (YYYY-MM-DD): ')
        if event_date in event_dict:
            for event_name in event_dict[event_date]:
            print 'Event Name: %s'% event_name
    else:
        print 'The date does not exist. Enter a valid date.'
    if action == 'info':
        event_name = raw_input('Event name? ')
        if event_name in event_dict[event_name]:
            print 'Event name %s' % event_name
            print 'Date %s' % event_date
            print 'Location %s' % event_location
            print 'Description %s' % event_description
            continue
    else:
        print 'Only commands can be entered. Please enter a command 
(add, list, info, or quit).'
        continue
```

I know the issue is with nested dictionaries.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is all based on user input and storing this input and being able to retrieve the input.

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: You realize you never actually add anything to `event_dict`?